# Grouping on a Node-Set in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping

I'm aware of the Muenchian grouping method for XSLT, but all implementations I've seen rely on a single node as the value to group on. In this case I'd like to group on a node-set. In the input below I'd like to group on outputs/output part ref.

I've tried to construct keys such as

```
<xsl:key name="refsKey" match="/processes/process" use="outputs/output_part_ref"/>
```

Of course outputs/output_part_ref matches the first node and doesn't match the node-set.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processes>
    <process>
        <name>ProcessA</name>
        <input_qty>1200</input_qty>
        <outputs>
            <output_part_ref>1</output_part_ref>
            <output_part_ref>2</output_part_ref>
            <output_part_ref>3</output_part_ref>
        </outputs>
    </process>
    <process>
        <name>ProcessB</name>
        <input_qty>1300</input_qty>
        <outputs>
            <output_part_ref>1</output_part_ref>
            <output_part_ref>2</output_part_ref>
            <output_part_ref>3</output_part_ref>
        </outputs>
    </process>
    <process>
        <name>ProcessC</name>
        <input_qty>770</input_qty>
        <outputs>
            <output_part_ref>1</output_part_ref>
            <output_part_ref>2</output_part_ref>
        </outputs>
    </process>
</processes>
```

**Sample Output**

```
<html>
...
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>2500</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>770</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
...
</html>
```

Comment: Is the possible number of `output_part_ref` fixed?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this: you need to sort the node-set and concatenate (recursively) the individual values in order to get a suitable key value. IOW, you need to make (at least) two passes here.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, the number and order of output_part_ref nodes is not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of elements forming the key is not fixed then I agree with Michael, we need to compute the key first and use `exsl:node-set` or similar in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="refsKey" match="process" use="key"/>

<xsl:variable name="rtf1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="processes/process" mode="key"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="process" mode="key">
  <xsl:copy>
    <key>
      <xsl:for-each select="outputs/output_part_ref">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">|</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </key>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="ns1" select="exsl:node-set($rtf1)/process"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processes">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$ns1[generate-id() = generate-id(key('refsKey', key)[1])]"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="process">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('refsKey', key)/input_qty)"/></td>
    <xsl:for-each select="outputs/output_part_ref">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **1.** If you agree with me, then you have to sort them first, because (IIUC) `1|2|3|` needs to be grouped together with `1|3|2|`. **2.** I am curious what difference having a fixed number of nodes would have made.

Comment: I added the sorting when concatenating the key values. If there were a fixed (and sorted) number of elements then you could define the key when writing the stylesheet e.g. `use="concat(outputs/output_part_ref[1], '|', outputs/output_part_ref[2], '|', outputs/output_part_ref[3])"`.

Comment: I see. Actually, you could this even with a variable count, as long as there is a **maximum** number of expected nodes.

Comment: BTW, I believe you have a mistake in `xsl:if test="position() > 1">`; it should be `xsl:if test="position()!=last()">`, IMHO. Or you could remove it altogether and just append a `'|'` indiscriminately.

Comment: No, with the order of `<xsl:if test="position() > 1">|</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="."/>` the output will be e.g. `1` + `|2` + `|3` which is what I want. The `position() != last()` can also be used but then you need the `value-of` first and then the output of the separator character within the check.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thank you for this. For the implementation I'll have to hope that MSXML2 supports exsl. This answer has also given me a greater insight into how templates / apply-templates works. I do wonder why you've added a [1] condition on the node-set returned by key('refsKey', key), it appears redundant to me.

Comment: @Horba, for MSXML you need to define `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` and use `msxsl:node-set` instead of `exsl:node-set`. As for the positional predicate `[1]` in `generate-id(key('refsKey', key)[1])`, the semantics is the same if you omit it as `generate-id` would take the id of the first item in a node set anyway but I usually spell it out, as it might make it more efficient and partly because I am used to it.

Comment: I see. I missed the fact this was **before** the actual value.