# How to transform xml document using mode

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML document with all nodes of "a" and output below in XML having "b" , "c" nodes

```
<a>

   <a>

     <a>

           <a/>

     </a>

  </a>

 <a/>

</a>
```

```
<b> 

    <c>

         <b>

            <c/>

         </b>

    </c>


  <c/>

</b>
```

How to transform into output because I do not get idea in my mind.

I am trying to use mode but yet mode are not clear to me how to use mode for each element

or do I need to to use condition like if or when to check the node and change the name of the node

with some replace commands in XSLT, because I need to use pair of template here to solve this

problem

Comment: The question is not specific enough. In XSLT you match parts of an XML DOM, copy them into the output, generate new nodes depending on them or call named template with them.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[count(ancestor::a) mod 2 = 0]">
  <b>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </b>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[count(ancestor::a) mod 2 = 1]">
  <c>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </c>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the output

```
<b>

   <c>

     <b>

           <c/>

     </b>

  </c>

 <c/>

</b>
```

for the input

```
<a>

   <a>

     <a>

           <a/>

     </a>

  </a>

 <a/>

</a>
```

I get the result you want for the input sample you posted. You will need to explain with more text what you want to achieve as currently I am not sure whether the level is all that is needed to decide whether `a` transforms to `b` or to `c`.

Comment: I need to write templates with modes to get output, first level to b, second level to c third level again to b.

Comment: Do you have some homework to do that asks you to write a solution using modes or why do you want to use modes? I know how to use modes but I don't see how they are needed for the transformation you ask for.

Comment: I try understand the use of mode in this situation thats why I need to use mode in this problem

Comment: out put is not correct should be <b> then <c> and then <b>

Comment: I have edited the answer and provided the output I get which seems to be exactly the one you posted as the desired solution.

Comment: How can I use the same recipe using mode, I tried to use but giving totally different output

Comment: Using a modes is necessary and helpful if you want to process the same node twice, I don't see why you want to do that for the transformation you have described. You seem to want to transform the same type of nodes in different ways but as long as a match pattern allows us to distinguish that I don't see how modes help. Sorry, maybe someone else will understand what you want to achieve with modes in this case, I don't understand it. For instance in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010791/grouping-on-a-node-set-in-xslt/23011593#23011593 I did a two step transformation which uses a mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really wanted to use modes, this is an example of how to do it

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="b"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a" mode="b">
      <b>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="c"/>
      </b>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a" mode="c">
      <c>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="b"/>
      </c>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, to start with, the template `<xsl:template match="/">` matches the document node. You then select the first **a** element in mode "b"

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="b"/>
```

And there is a corresponding template match for this mode

```
<xsl:template match="a" mode="b">
```

Within in this, you create a **b** element, then select the child elements, this time using mode "c"

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="c"/>
```

And similarly, this template outpus a **c** element, but then switches back to selecting **a** elements in mode "b", so the two templates alternate between each other.

Without the mode, you would have two templates matching the element **a**

```
<xsl:template match="a">
```

Having two templates that match the same element like this is considered an error, as the XSLT processor cannot decide which one to use.

Of course, you simplify this slightly, if you assume that outputting **b** is the default behaviour, then this would also work

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="a">
      <b>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="c"/>
      </b>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a" mode="c">
      <c>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
      </c>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Having said all this, as Martin Honnen points out, you do not need to use Modes in this particular. If you already have a way to distinguish between the **a** elements using an XPath expression, then you can just as easily use that.